# How do I change active build configuration in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Any time I compile, build or run my project it outputs the exe file into the **Debug\Win32**  folder, so I guess it is in debug mode.

When I go to : Project->Options I can see the debug(active)

But I don't know how to switch to release. When I change the combo to release, debug is still active.

Answer (score 15):

1. Open the project manager from the View menu, or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F11</kbd>.
2. Find the Build Configurations node in the project manager's tree view and open it up.
3. Double click on Release.

[image]

The active build configuration is indicated in the project manager by boldface text.